# Calories uptake and reduce

Tags: calories

If I eat something that has 200 calories, and say it's like a chocolate bar or maybe even a couple of beers is that the amount of calories I would have to work off? I guess the second part to that question is, does the body convert all calories or do some calories just pass through without getting absorbed?